# Disabled all services in msconfig - login no longer working

Tags: windows-10, boot, login

I disabled all services in services using `msconfig` and restarted.

Now - my login details no longer work. I have no network access and the `forgot my password option` doesn't do anything.

I have restarted using shift+restart to try get into safe mode but this just brings me to the same logon page.

Does anybody know what caused this or how I can resolve the issue?

Comment: Take a look: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/accidentally-disabbled-all-services-in-msconfig-in/1806556e-c9a4-400d-bc1b-2a5cf9804458?auth=1

Comment: Why did you disable all services?

Comment: Because I'm an idiot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got lucky this time.

Tried an old password for the user which got me logged in. Went straight to `msconfig` and re-enabled them all and restarted.

Comment: I forgot to mention another piece of advice for EVERYONE --- Make SURE you have created at least ONE other BACKUP account!!  I've had to use it numerous times.  So, if your login is USER, also create a USER-BKUP account, and then ALSO make sure it has ADMIN rights.  Use the same PW for both.  -- This is part of the "New PC SETUP" advice we include in our new app.  It ALSO allowed me THIS WEEK, to SHUT DOWN Auto-install to Creator's Edition, as Microsoft update had TAKEN OVER ALL SCREENS.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the best examples of where an extra user account, and either a restore point or an image backup is a requirement.  REGARDLESS, try these:

Try to get into RECOVERY CONSOLE, (Google it), and try various recovery options.

If you can't get there from your keyboard, use and boot a Windows DVD.

Worst case, get someone familiar with registry tools and turn all the services back on, by hand.  Just because you can't boot, doesn't mean that you can't access and change anything on your hard drive.

On ANY of these options, if you can, BEFORE you attempt a repair, at least DO an image backup FIRST!!  Then you can try to fix it as many times as you like.  Better still, restore it to a new hard drive and try to fix the restored image, and don't touch the hard drive you messed up.  Try Restore points and Windows Repair first. (But, I've had Restore Points and Windows Repair destroy booting, once on a brand new WORKING PC, under Dell's direction, when just testing restores and repairs.  I was only able to boot 10 minutes later, after using the "RESTORE FACTORY IMAGE" from repair console.)

**UPDATE: Another solution, which is easiest if you have another account.** (From Tom Celic, original question author, that thought of this on his own, used it, solved his own problem, and then posted this answer below:)
"Try to log in using a different user account if you had already created an extra user account with admin rights, and THEN go to MSConfig to turn all the services back on."

**Advice for EVERYONE:  === >>  Create an EXTRA ADMIN account, NOW!**
You need to have already created at least ONE other BACKUP account to solve problems like this!! I've had to use it numerous times. So, if your login name is "USER", also create a "USER-BKUP" account, which must have ADMIN rights. Use the same PW for both accounts, unless your account "USER" is not running as admin. -- This is part of the advice we will be providing in our new "Setup My New PC" app, in our SnapBack.com. I used this extra account this week to regain control, and STOP the FORCED Auto-install of Creator's Edition.

(I DO like your reason why you made your mistake---you made my day! :) -- Hey, we are all Bozo's, occasionally.)

Comment: I got it fixed - I used an old password for the user which got me logged in and allowed me to re-enable all the services. Phew. Cheers for the answer - hopefully it can fix the next person who pulls the door closed on themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Use this tutorial to access System Restore from Advanced Boot Options: [How to Start System Restore When You Can No Longer Log Into Windows](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-start-system-restore-when-you-can-no-longer-log-windows). Then restore your system to an older state, before the time you made those changes.

Here is also a summary of the steps involved:

1. Boot from a recovery medium (CD, DVD, USB memory stick, recovery partition, etc)
2. Choose Troubleshoot.
3. Choose Advanced options.
4. Choose System Restore.
5. Login with your user account.
6. Follow the System Restore wizard to revert Windows 10 to a working state.

Again, that tutorial explains everything in more details, with screenshots included. It was made for Windows 8.1 but it applies to Windows 10 just as well.

Comment: Please note if you want to promote or recommend your own product/blog, there are some [guidelines in place](https://superuser.com/help/promotion) for doing so. Following them will help you avoid giving the impression that you're spamming. Could you please [edit] to explicitly state your affiliation? Thanks. (If you're not actually affiliated, it may be worth mentioning that as well.)

Answer (score 0):

I have rectified the problems by:

1. Booting into Ubuntu OS (created booted USB of Ubuntu OS through mobile app "EtchDroid"). It has "try Ubuntu option" Which doesn't install OS (completely works faster).
   2.And I renamed the magnify file with cmd file(interchanged), present in the C drive > windows > system32 through Ubuntu file explorer.
   (Now the magnify file is the cmd program.)
2. Then Rebooted into windows 10 and selected magnify option. Then the cmd program opens.
3. Entered "msconfig" In the command.
4. System configuration box appears. In the service tab selected "enable all and restarted.
5. Everything works fine...
   Those steps are made completely without logging in to the PC (windows 10). I have not lost even a single file and everything remains.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a few weeks ago and I couldn't find any good answers one the internet. After 2 days of going through BIOS, trying to get into command prompt, and guessing passwords I figured out that it was the associated Microsoft account's password (for me at least). I was in the process of trying to make a bootable USB but I was able to access everything and re-enable what I needed to.

Also a really big help is having a backup admin account on your computer for situations like these.

Answer (score -1):

I will add this simple solution which is simply to wait on your windows 10 session log in, after 10-15 minutes your name session will appear then after 10-15 minutes you will be able to enter your password.

You can hit the enter key several time during the process (I don't know if it helps but I did it)

Jeremy

Answer (score -1):

Change Values in the Registry Editor
You can use the winRE registry editor to disable password-less (PIN) login.
To do so:

Access winRE..
Recovery > advanced options screen > open Command Prompt.

Type regedit and press Enter to launch the Registry Editor.

check this link for more specific details:

[https://www.technewstoday.com/something-happened-and-your-pin-isnt-available/#:~:text=“Something](https://www.technewstoday.com/something-happened-and-your-pin-isnt-available/#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CSomething) went wrong and your,Microsoft Account, that's even easier.

Select HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and click File > Load Hive from the menu.

registry-load-hive

The hive files will be in C:\Windows\System32\config

Note: Replace C: with whatever drive your OS is installed on.

Load the SOFTWARE hive. Name the file zsoftware. This will give you a new listing under HKLM.

Fix 1, Navigate to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\zsoftware\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\PasswordLess\Device

Change the value of DevicePasswordLessBuildVersion from 2 to 0. This will turn off the Require Windows Hello for sign-in setting.

Reboot your PC.

You should be able to log in using your password now. If you receive an incorrect password, try to login using microsoft account password